# transformation of graph of single-variable function

Tags: functions

Given a function *f:R $\rightarrow$ R* which is continuous everywhere.

We have a graph y=f(x)

Suppose I apply the following transformation:

1.translate the graph to the right by 3 units

2.Reduce the graph by $\frac{1}{2}$ times along x-axis

So after transformation (1), I have a graph y=f(x-3),

but after transformation (2), Which graph should I have, y=f(2x-3) or y=f(2(x-3))?